# Github Actions fails on deploying to Azkaban

Tags: docker, github-actions, azkaban

I'm deploying app with github actions and getting error when trying to deploy to Azkaban with docker image. Any ideas what I should do?

````
./docker-run.sh: 4: cd: can't cd to target/deployment
chmod: cannot access './script.sh': No such file or directory
./docker-run.sh: 6: ./docker-run.sh: ./script.sh: not found
Error: Error: The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 127```
````

Comment: Please provide some more info. Here are some hints on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks! The issue was wrong docker image.